# Custom navigation Bar with image

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar

I want to make custom navigation Bar with image 320x200. Can I do it? I not see such apps in iTunes I want to know is it possible ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any restriction on Apple's side neither in iOS Developer Program's contract or its appendices which says that is not possible to do. so, I guess you can do such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if Apple would permit a navigation bar of that size, but that aside then the approach I just documented here would work, but you would have to do navigation stack type management yourself

[How to persist a slide-out sidebar menu through entire iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973896/how-to-persist-a-slide-out-sidebar-menu-through-entire-ios-app/22974006#22974006)